# How to display LaTeX symbols in the xtick labels in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, label, latex, matlab-figure

I am trying to plot the following:

```
figure
plot([0,10000],[20,20])
set(gca,'XTick',[0 10000])
set(gca,'XTickLabel',({'0','\phi', 'interpreter', 'latex'}))
```

But I am not able to display `\phi` as the Greek letter.

Comment: I removed the extraneous ) after the 10000 in the set(gca line but then it worked fine for me - R2016b. Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: The  extraneous ) was a mistake. I am not getting any error but I do not see `\phi` as the greek letter but just as `\phi`

Comment: I am using R2014a

Comment: You can use `set(gca,'xticklabel',{'0', char(1060)})` alternatively

Comment: Try `$\phi$`, I think you needed equation mode in the past

Comment: Wait, you are not setting the interpreter to latex, you are setting the labels to the word `interpreter` and `latex` ?!?!

Comment: To see what I mean, do `set(gca,'XTick',[0 2000 4000 10000])` :D

Comment: @AnderBiguri I do not understand

Comment: @SardarUsama it is not showing the character but an empy space.

Comment: what do you get by entering  `feature('DefaultCharacterSet')` in the command window?

Comment: @SardarUsama `windows-1252`

Comment: Try with these options instead of `char(1060)` : `char(934)` or `char(966)`

Comment: @SardarUsama Still getting the same empty space

Comment: I am afraid there is no solution https://ch.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/83114-print-latex-greek-chars-to-commandline

Answer (score 4):

### In newer versions of MATLAB...

...this can be accomplished by setting the [`'TickLabelInterpreter'` property](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.axis.axes-properties.html#budumk7-TickLabelInterpreter) to `'latex'`. Here's an example in R2016b:

```
figure();
plot([0 10000], [20 20]);
set(gca, 'XTick', [0 10000]);
set(gca, 'XTickLabel', {'0', '$\phi$'}, 'TickLabelInterpreter', 'latex');
```

[image]

### In older versions of MATLAB...

...before the `'TickLabelInterpreter'` property was added, the easiest way I know of to add Greek letters to axes tick labels is to change the [`'FontName'` property](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.axis.axes-properties.html#budumk7_sep_shared-FontName) to `'symbol'`. Here's an example from R2013a:

```
figure();
plot([0 10000], [20 20]);
set(gca, 'XTick', [0 10000]);
set(gca, 'XTickLabel', {'0', 'f'}, 'FontName', 'symbol');
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You are setting the labels to the words `'interpreter'` and '`latex'`. To see what I mean run:

```
figure
plot([0,10000],[20,20])
set(gca,'XTick',[0 2000 4000 10000])
set(gca,'xticklabel',({'0','\phi', 'interpreter', 'latex'}))
```

[image]

(note that my default interpreter is latex so \phi shows correctly)

If you want, in general a latex interpreter, you can set the default of MATLAB as:

```
set(0, 'defaultTextInterpreter', 'latex');
```

and you dont need to worry about latex anymore.

Comment: I was trying in that way but I was getting the following error `The name 'interpreter' is not an accessible property for an instance of class 'axes'.
`

Comment: @emax yes sorry, that was my bad. Unfortunately I do not have access to an old version of MATLAB to test this more, so I can only give advice on how to set the default interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

A really dirty way to do it is to add a picture of phi on the tick place. The problem with this is the background of the figure. By default this is grey, but when saving the figure this becomes white, so if your picture has a white background, you let it be so you can save it, or change it to the background of the figure (or change the background of the figure to white so you cover both cases at onces).

The code

```
figure
plot([0,10000],[20,20])
set(gca,'XTick',[0 10000])
set(gca,'xticklabel',{'0',''})

% get needed stuff
bg = get(gcf, 'color');   % or set(gcf, 'color',[1 1 1]) to change background of figure to white
box = get(gca, 'Position');
ticklength = get(gca, 'TickLength');
tightinset = get(gca, 'TightInset');
xlims = get(gca, 'XLim');
I = imread('phi.png');

% change white background of picture to background of figure
% for ii=1:3
%     tmp = I(:,:,ii);
%     tmp(tmp == 255) = bg(ii)*255;
%     I(:,:,ii) = tmp;
% end

% position of image
xpos = box(1) + (10000 - xlims(1)) * (box(3)) / (xlims(2) - xlims(1)) - ticklength(1);
ypos = box(2) - tightinset(2) + ticklength(2);

axes('position', [xpos ypos ticklength(1) ticklength(2)])  %[0.9400 0.9400 0.9400]

image(I)
set(gca, 'visible','off')
```

results in

[image: figure with phi]